# how to generate ValueLink merchant working keys

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, ofbiz, diffie-hellman

I am trying to generate ValueLink merchant working keys using a modified version of the apache ofbiz [ValueLinkApi Class](http://ci.apache.org/projects/ofbiz/site/javadocs/org/ofbiz/accounting/thirdparty/valuelink/ValueLinkApi.html) - [src](http://kickjava.com/src/org/ofbiz/accounting/thirdparty/valuelink/ValueLinkApi.java.htm)

I've modified it only to the extent of making it a standalone class that I can run from outside the context of the ofbiz framework.

My program runs without error but my keys are not being accepted by the api.

Have you ever implemented this?  Did you use this library or something else like openSSL? If you used this library did you have to modify it at all?

heres my version:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyAgreement;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.interfaces.DHPrivateKey;
import javax.crypto.interfaces.DHPublicKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.DHParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.DHPrivateKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.DHPublicKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

import org.ofbiz.base.util.Debug;
import org.ofbiz.base.util.StringUtil;

public class diffHel {

    public static final String module = "diffHel";

    //were in props
    public String publicValue = "6B0276780D3E07911D744F545833005E8C2F755E0FE59A8660527F7B7E070A45EEB853DA70C6EFE2B8BF278F0B4A334A49DF0985635745A3DAD2E85A9C0EEFAE657CC382A0B3EAE9C3F85B0A2305282612CFD2857801131EC9FE313DB9DADFB914A30EE077E8A97E5574CE5BD56661B021C39116913710947FAA38FFCB4FC045";
    public String format = "ddMMyyyyHHmmss";
    public String primeHex = "e516e43e5457b2f66f6ca367b335ead8319939fa4df6c1b7f86e73e922a6d19393255e419096668174e35c818a66117f799e8666c8050ee436f9801351606c55d45faba03f39e2923ba926a9cd75d4bdbca9de78b62a9b847a781c692c063eaacb43a396f01d121d042755d0b7c0b2dfa8b498a57e4d90c30ca049a7ac2b7f73";
    public String genString = "05";

    //were generic values
    public String exchangeKey;
    public String privateKey = ""; 

    protected SecretKey kek = null;
    protected SecretKey mwk = null;
    protected String merchantId = null;
    protected String terminalId = null;
    protected Long mwkIndex = null;
    protected boolean debug = false;

    public StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

    public diffHel() {}

    /**
     * Output the creation of public/private keys + KEK to the console for manual database update
     */
    public StringBuffer outputKeyCreation(boolean kekOnly, String kekTest) {
        return this.outputKeyCreation(0, kekOnly, kekTest);
    }

    private StringBuffer outputKeyCreation(int loop, boolean kekOnly, String kekTest) {
        //StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        loop++;

        if (loop > 100) {
            // only loop 100 times; then throw an exception
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to create 128 byte keys in 100 tries");
        }

        // place holder for the keys
        DHPrivateKey privateKey = null;
        DHPublicKey publicKey = null;

        if (!kekOnly) {
            KeyPair keyPair = null;
            try {
                keyPair = this.createKeys();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                Debug.logError(e, module);
            } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
                Debug.logError(e, module);
            } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                Debug.logError(e, module);
            }

            if (keyPair != null) {
                publicKey = (DHPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
                privateKey = (DHPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

               buf.append("privateKeyLenth=" + privateKey.getX().toByteArray().length);


                if (publicKey == null || publicKey.getY().toByteArray().length != 128) {
                    // run again until we get a 128 byte public key for VL
                    return this.outputKeyCreation(loop, kekOnly, kekTest);
                }
            } else {
                Debug.log("Returned a null KeyPair", module);
                return this.outputKeyCreation(loop, kekOnly, kekTest);
            }
        } else {
            // use our existing private key to generate a KEK
            try {
                privateKey = (DHPrivateKey) this.getPrivateKey();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.logError(e, module);
            }
        }

        // the KEK
        byte[] kekBytes = null;
        try {
            kekBytes = this.generateKek(privateKey);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        }

        // the 3DES KEK value
        SecretKey loadedKek = this.getDesEdeKey(kekBytes);
        byte[] loadKekBytes = loadedKek.getEncoded();


        // test the KEK
        //Cipher cipher = this.getCipher(this.getKekKey(), Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        Cipher cipher = this.getCipher(loadedKek, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        byte[] kekTestB = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        byte[] kekTestC = new byte[0];
        if (kekTest != null) {
            kekTestB = StringUtil.fromHexString(kekTest);
        }

        // encrypt the test bytes
        try {
            kekTestC = cipher.doFinal(kekTestB);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        }

        kek = loadedKek;

        byte[] newMwk = generateMwk(loadedKek);

        byte[] decyptedMwk = decryptViaKek(newMwk);

        if (!kekOnly) {
            // public key (just Y)
            BigInteger y = publicKey.getY();
            byte[] yBytes = y.toByteArray();
            String yHex = StringUtil.toHexString(yBytes);
            buf.append("======== Begin Public Key (Y @ " + yBytes.length + " / " + yHex.length() + ") ========\n");
            buf.append(yHex + "\n");
            buf.append("======== End Public Key ========\n\n");

            // private key (just X)
            BigInteger x = privateKey.getX();
            byte[] xBytes = x.toByteArray();
            String xHex = StringUtil.toHexString(xBytes);
            buf.append("======== Begin Private Key (X @ " + xBytes.length + " / " + xHex.length() + ") ========\n");
            buf.append(xHex + "\n");
            buf.append("======== End Private Key ========\n\n");

            // private key (full)
            byte[] privateBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
            String privateHex = StringUtil.toHexString(privateBytes);
            buf.append("======== Begin Private Key (Full @ " + privateBytes.length + " / " + privateHex.length() + ") ========\n");
            buf.append(privateHex + "\n");
            buf.append("======== End Private Key ========\n\n");
        }

        if (kekBytes != null) {
            buf.append("======== Begin KEK aka decrypted MWK (" + kekBytes.length + ") ========\n");
            buf.append(StringUtil.toHexString(kekBytes) + "\n");
            buf.append("======== End KEK ========\n\n");

            buf.append("======== Begin KEK (DES) (" + loadKekBytes.length + ") ========\n");
            buf.append(StringUtil.toHexString(loadKekBytes) + "\n");
            buf.append("======== End KEK (DES) ========\n\n");

            buf.append("======== Begin KEK Test (" + kekTestC.length + ") ========\n");
            buf.append(StringUtil.toHexString(kekTestC) + "\n");
            buf.append("======== End KEK Test ========\n\n");
        } else {
            Debug.logError("KEK came back empty", module);
        }
        if (newMwk != null) {
            buf.append("======== Begin MWK (" + newMwk.length + ") ========\n");
            buf.append(StringUtil.toHexString(newMwk) + "\n");
            buf.append("======== End MWK ========\n\n");
        }
        if (decyptedMwk != null) {
            buf.append("======== Begin Decrypted MWK (" + decyptedMwk.length + ") ========\n");
            buf.append(StringUtil.toHexString(decyptedMwk) + "\n");
            buf.append("======== End Decrypted MWK ========\n\n");
        }

        return buf;
    }

    /**
     * Create a set of public/private keys using ValueLinks defined parameters
     * @return KeyPair object containing both public and private keys
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
     */
    public KeyPair createKeys() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        // initialize the parameter spec
        DHPublicKey publicKey = (DHPublicKey) this.getValueLinkPublicKey();
        DHParameterSpec dhParamSpec = publicKey.getParams();
        //Debug.log(dhParamSpec.getP().toString() + " / " + dhParamSpec.getG().toString(), module);

        // create the public/private key pair using parameters defined by valuelink
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
        keyGen.initialize(dhParamSpec);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

        return keyPair;
    }

    /**
     * Generate a key exchange key for use in encrypting the mwk
     * @param privateKey The private key for the merchant
     * @return byte array containing the kek
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws InvalidKeySpecException
     * @throws InvalidKeyException
     */
    public byte[] generateKek(PrivateKey privateKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException {
        // get the ValueLink public key
        PublicKey vlPublic = this.getValueLinkPublicKey();

        // generate shared secret key
        KeyAgreement ka = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
        ka.init(privateKey);
        ka.doPhase(vlPublic, true);

        byte[] secretKey = ka.generateSecret();




        buf.append("======== Secret Key (" + secretKey.length + ") ========\n");
        buf.append(StringUtil.toHexString(secretKey) + "\n");
        buf.append("======== End Secret Key ========\n\n");


        if (debug) {
            Debug.log("Secret Key : " + StringUtil.toHexString(secretKey) + " / " + secretKey.length,  module);
        }

        // generate 3DES from secret key using VL algorithm (KEK)
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        byte[] digest = md.digest(secretKey);
        byte[] des2 = getByteRange(digest, 0, 16);
        byte[] first8 = getByteRange(des2, 0, 8);
        byte[] kek = copyBytes(des2, first8, 0);

        if (debug) {
            Debug.log("Generated KEK : " + StringUtil.toHexString(kek) + " / " + kek.length, module);
        }


        return kek;


    }

    /**
     * Get a public key object for the ValueLink supplied public key
     * @return PublicKey object of ValueLinks's public key
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws InvalidKeySpecException
     */
    public PublicKey getValueLinkPublicKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        // read the valuelink public key
        //String publicValue = (String) props.get("payment.valuelink.publicValue");
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = StringUtil.fromHexString(publicValue);

        // initialize the parameter spec
        DHParameterSpec dhParamSpec = this.getDHParameterSpec();

        // load the valuelink public key
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
        BigInteger publicKeyInt = new BigInteger(publicKeyBytes);
        DHPublicKeySpec dhPublicSpec = new DHPublicKeySpec(publicKeyInt, dhParamSpec.getP(), dhParamSpec.getG());
        PublicKey vlPublic = keyFactory.generatePublic(dhPublicSpec);

        return vlPublic;
    }

    /**
     * Get merchant Private Key
     * @return PrivateKey object for the merchant
     */
    public PrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = this.getPrivateKeyBytes();

        // initialize the parameter spec
        DHParameterSpec dhParamSpec = this.getDHParameterSpec();

        // load the private key
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
        BigInteger privateKeyInt = new BigInteger(privateKeyBytes);
        DHPrivateKeySpec dhPrivateSpec = new DHPrivateKeySpec(privateKeyInt, dhParamSpec.getP(), dhParamSpec.getG());
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(dhPrivateSpec);

        return privateKey;
    }

    /**
     * Generate a new MWK
     * @return Hex String of the new encrypted MWK ready for transmission to ValueLink
     */
    public byte[] generateMwk() {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = null;
        try {
            keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);

        }

        // generate the DES key 1
        SecretKey des1 = keyGen.generateKey();
        SecretKey des2 = keyGen.generateKey();

        if (des1 != null && des2 != null) {
            byte[] desByte1 = des1.getEncoded();
            byte[] desByte2 = des2.getEncoded();
            byte[] desByte3 = des1.getEncoded();

            // check for weak keys
            try {
                if (DESKeySpec.isWeak(des1.getEncoded(), 0) || DESKeySpec.isWeak(des2.getEncoded(), 0)) {
                    return generateMwk();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.logError(e, module);
            }

            byte[] des3 = copyBytes(desByte1, copyBytes(desByte2, desByte3, 0), 0);
            return generateMwk(des3);
        } else {
            Debug.log("Null DES keys returned", module);
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Generate a new MWK
     * @param desBytes byte array of the DES key (24 bytes)
     * @return Hex String of the new encrypted MWK ready for transmission to ValueLink
     */
    public byte[] generateMwk(byte[] desBytes) {
        if (debug) {
            Debug.log("DES Key : " + StringUtil.toHexString(desBytes) + " / " + desBytes.length, module);
        }
        SecretKeyFactory skf1 = null;
        SecretKey mwk = null;
        try {
            skf1 = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        }
        DESedeKeySpec desedeSpec2 = null;
        try {
            desedeSpec2 = new DESedeKeySpec(desBytes);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        }
        if (skf1 != null && desedeSpec2 != null) {
            try {
                mwk = skf1.generateSecret(desedeSpec2);
            } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                Debug.logError(e, module);
            }
        }
        if (mwk != null) {
            return generateMwk(mwk);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generate a new MWK
     * @param mwkdes3 pre-generated DES3 SecretKey
     * @return Hex String of the new encrypted MWK ready for transmission to ValueLink
     */
    public byte[] generateMwk(SecretKey mwkdes3) {
        // zeros for checksum
        byte[] zeros = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        // 8 bytes random data
        byte[] random = new byte[8];
        Random ran = new Random();
        ran.nextBytes(random);


        // open a cipher using the new mwk
        Cipher cipher = this.getCipher(mwkdes3, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);

        // make the checksum - encrypted 8 bytes of 0's
        byte[] encryptedZeros = new byte[0];
        try {
            encryptedZeros = cipher.doFinal(zeros);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        }

        // make the 40 byte MWK - random 8 bytes + key + checksum
        byte[] newMwk = copyBytes(mwkdes3.getEncoded(), encryptedZeros, 0);
        newMwk = copyBytes(random, newMwk, 0);

        if (debug) {
            Debug.log("Random 8 byte : " + StringUtil.toHexString(random), module);
            Debug.log("Encrypted 0's : " + StringUtil.toHexString(encryptedZeros), module);
            Debug.log("Decrypted MWK : " + StringUtil.toHexString(mwkdes3.getEncoded()) + " / " + mwkdes3.getEncoded().length, module);
            Debug.log("Encrypted MWK : " + StringUtil.toHexString(newMwk) + " / " + newMwk.length, module);
        }

        return newMwk;
    }

    /**
     * Use the KEK to encrypt a value usually the MWK
     * @param content byte array to encrypt
     * @return encrypted byte array
     */
    public byte[] encryptViaKek(byte[] content) {
        return cryptoViaKek(content, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
    }

    /**
     * Ue the KEK to decrypt a value
     * @param content byte array to decrypt
     * @return decrypted byte array
     */
    public byte[] decryptViaKek(byte[] content) {
        return cryptoViaKek(content, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a date string formatted as directed by ValueLink
     * @return ValueLink formatted date String
     */
    public String getDateString() {
        //String format = (String) props.get("payment.valuelink.timestamp");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        return sdf.format(new Date());
    }

 // using the prime and generator provided by valuelink; create a parameter object
    protected DHParameterSpec getDHParameterSpec() {
        //String primeHex = (String) props.get("payment.valuelink.prime");
        //String genString = (String) props.get("payment.valuelink.generator");

        // convert the p/g hex values
        byte[] primeByte = StringUtil.fromHexString(this.primeHex);
        BigInteger prime = new BigInteger(1, primeByte); // force positive (unsigned)
        BigInteger generator = new BigInteger(this.genString);

        // initialize the parameter spec
        DHParameterSpec dhParamSpec = new DHParameterSpec(prime, generator, 1024);

        return dhParamSpec;
    }

    // actual kek encryption/decryption code
    protected byte[] cryptoViaKek(byte[] content, int mode) {
        // open a cipher using the kek for transport
        Cipher cipher = this.getCipher(this.getKekKey(), mode);
        byte[] dec = new byte[0];
        try {
            dec = cipher.doFinal(content);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        }
        return dec;
    }

 // return a cipher for a key - DESede/CBC/NoPadding IV = 0
    protected Cipher getCipher(SecretKey key, int mode) {
        byte[] zeros = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(zeros);

        // create the Cipher - DESede/CBC/NoPadding
        Cipher mwkCipher = null;
        try {
            mwkCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
            return null;
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        }
        try {
            mwkCipher.init(mode, key, iv);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, "Invalid key", module);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            Debug.logError(e, module);
        }
        return mwkCipher;
    }

    protected SecretKey getKekKey() {
        if (kek == null) {
            kek = this.getDesEdeKey(getKek());
        }

        if (debug) {
            Debug.log("Raw KEK : " + StringUtil.toHexString(getKek()), module);
            Debug.log("KEK : " + StringUtil.toHexString(kek.getEncoded()), module);
        }

        return kek;
    }

    protected SecretKey getDesEdeKey(byte[] rawKey) {
        SecretKeyFactory skf = null;
        try {
            skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // should never happen since DESede is a standard algorithm
            Debug.logError(e, module);
            return null;
        }

        // load the raw key
        if (rawKey.length > 0) {
            DESedeKeySpec desedeSpec1 = null;
            try {
                desedeSpec1 = new DESedeKeySpec(rawKey);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                Debug.logError(e, "Not a valid DESede key", module);
                return null;
            }

            // create the SecretKey Object
            SecretKey key = null;
            try {
                key = skf.generateSecret(desedeSpec1);
            } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                Debug.logError(e, module);
            }
            return key;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No valid DESede key available");
        }
    }

    protected byte[] getKek() {
        //return StringUtil.fromHexString(this.getGenericValue().getString("exchangeKey"));
        return StringUtil.fromHexString(this.exchangeKey);
    }

    protected byte[] getPrivateKeyBytes() {
        //return StringUtil.fromHexString(this.getGenericValue().getString("privateKey"));
        return StringUtil.fromHexString(this.privateKey);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new byte[] from the offset of the defined byte[] with a specific number of bytes
     * @param bytes The byte[] to extract from
     * @param offset The starting postition
     * @param length The number of bytes to copy
     * @return a new byte[]
     */
    public static byte[] getByteRange(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length) {
        byte[] newBytes = new byte[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            newBytes[i] = bytes[offset + i];
        }
        return newBytes;
    }

    /**
     * Copies a byte[] into another byte[] starting at a specific position
     * @param source byte[] to copy from
     * @param target byte[] coping into
     * @param position the position on target where source will be copied to
     * @return a new byte[]
     */
    public static byte[] copyBytes(byte[] source, byte[] target, int position) {
        byte[] newBytes = new byte[target.length + source.length];
        for (int i = 0, n = 0, x = 0; i < newBytes.length; i++) {
            if (i < position || i > (position + source.length - 2)) {
                newBytes[i] = target[n];
                n++;
            } else {
                for (; x < source.length; x++) {
                    newBytes[i] = source[x];
                    if (source.length - 1 > x) {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return newBytes;
    }


}
```